# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, sqlite

I use the following code to make a booking in a system yet it returns an error:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
choice = raw_input("What day would you like to book seats on? F/S : ")
if choice == "F":
    bookseats = [0,1]
    print"What seats would you like to book?"
    bookseats[0] = raw_input("Choice : ")
    bookseats[1] = raw_input("What is their user ID? : ")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Booked='N'")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        if row == None:
            break
        elif row[1] == bookseats[0] and row[4] == "N" and row[3] == "F":
            print "Seat Number:" , row[1] ,"Is now booked!"
            cur.execute("UPDATE seats SET Booked =N AND CustID=?", (bookseats[0]))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am really confused what the error is and how I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over the result of `rows = cur.fetchone()`, which retrieves just one row. Remove that line and just loop directly over the cursor:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Booked='N'")
for row in cur:
```

You do not need to test for `row == None` either, nor do you need to test if the `Booked` column is equal to `N`. Simplify the loop to:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Booked='N' AND CustID=?", (bookseats[0],))
row = cur.fetchone()
if row is not None and row[3] == "F":
    print "Seat Number:" , row[1] ,"Is now booked!"
    cur.execute("UPDATE seats SET Booked =N AND CustID=?", (bookseats[0]))
```

You can just ask the database for rows that match your `bookseats[0]` column, and where the 3rd column is set to `F`. You didn't show us your schema so it is hard to recommend how you can update your query for that.

Your `UPDATE` query is incorrect, you probably meant:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE seats SET Booked='Y' WHERE CustID=?", (bookseats[0],))
```

instead.

Your SQL query and update look suspect though; without knowing the full schema it does look as if you are mixing your seat number and customer number in places.

Comment: Hey - my UPDATE Query was what i meant it to be :) I use all that code that you suggested yet it doesnt seem to commit?

Comment: @CharlieSay: Call `conn.commit()`.

Comment: I do :) here is the code with conn.commit()                                         for row in cur:
                if row[1] == bookseats[0] and row[3] == "F":
                    print "Seat Number:" , row[1] ,"Is now booked!"
                    cur.execute("UPDATE seats SET Booked = 'B' AND CustID=?", (bookseats[0],))
                    conn.commit()

Answer (score 2):

`fetchone` doesn't return a list of rows, but one row only, so this is incorrect:

```
rows = cur.fetchone()
for row in rows:
```

Do, instead:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
```